# Spring boot mongodb criterias

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have the below mongodb collection:

```
module: [
 {
   "id": "b92816df-fcc7-4e0f-9524-f81d0a5097b4", 
   "interventions": [ 
       { 
         "lang": "en-US", 
         "name": "Mathematic"
         "coef": 5 
       }, 
       { 
         "lang": "fr-FR", 
         "name": "Mathematique"
         "coef": 6
       }
   ]
 }
]
```

and i want to do some search based on (lang AND (name like OR coef like) using spring boot mongoDB
How can i do this search using criteria or aggregation ...

PS: the search should return a Pageable of "module"

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$regex` Provides regular expression capabilities for pattern matching strings in queries. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#mongodb-query-op.-regex

Your second condition in OR with the **coef** field is incorrect. You can only use a comparison operator.

The query with mongo playground:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/5aG9SKjLwkh

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$and": [
        {
          "interventions.lang": "en-US"
        }
      ],
      "$or": [
        {
          "interventions.name": {
            $regex: "tiq",
            "$options": "i"
          }
        },
        {
          "interventions.coef": 5
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$skip": 0
  },
  {
    "$limit": 10
  }
])
```

With Spring Data MongoDB:

```
public Page<Module> getModulePage() {

    var pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 10);
    var criteria = new Criteria().andOperator(Criteria.where("interventions.lang").is("en-US")
            .orOperator(Criteria.where("interventions.name").regex("tiq", "i"), Criteria.where("interventions.coef").is(5)));

    var aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(List.of(Aggregation.match(criteria), skip((long) pageable.getPageNumber() * pageable.getPageSize()), limit(pageable.getPageSize())));

    var results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, Module.class, Module.class).getMappedResults();

    return new PageImpl<>(results, pageable, results.size());
}
```